# How to change font color in one column of attribute table in Composer reports?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2.8

How do you change the font color in just one column of the attribute table included in QGIS's Composer? I would like to have the numbers listed in color red just for one column out of four columns in the attribute table.

I don't see any options to do this under Composer > Items> Item Properties> Attributes menu. (using QGIS version 2.8.2)

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there's a single option to do this (yet) but an alternative would be to insert **multiple attribute tables** side-by-side by filtering out the columns for each one.

First add an attribute table and exclude all but one column.

[image: Filter attributes]

Add another attribute table, postition it next to the first table and exclude all but *another* column and so on. Then edit the font, styles, colours etc for each table:

[image: 4 separate tables side-by-side]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, Joseph, for your creative suggestion. Hopefully the ability for doing changes per column-- such as the font's style, size, color, etc., will be made easier in future qgis versions.

Comment: @user1568777 - Most welcome buddy! I agree it's not the most ideal and quick solution but I suppose it can get the job done. You could open a ticket ([feature request](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis)) describing this and hope it will be implemented in future QGIS versions =)